# Wrapping certain words by replacing '`' with tags

Tags: javascript, html, string

I'm trying to copy a bit of "markdown-behaviour". I'm trying to feed JS some text, for example, a string like so:

```
"This is some very very fancy `code example` to try out yourself!"
```

I want to replace the starting `` ` `` with `<div class="code">` and the terminating `` ` `` with `"</div>"` in order to highlight some stuff.
I've tried doing it with `.replace()` but can't get it to work without it including the text after the terminating `` ` ``.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? Are there more elegant solutions other than manually going through the String char by char?

Many thanks
Pasu-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var x = "Hello `code` World!".replace(/`([^`]+)`/g, "<div class='code'>$1</div>");

console.log(x);
```

Comment: Is there some site to see all the different search-thingies you can use..?

Comment: There are many sites for regexp. For example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @PascalStockert https://regex101.com/ — one of the best, with hints on hover)

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use regex to replace it.

```js
var str = 'This is some very very fancy `code example` to try out yourself!';

document.body.innerHTML += str.replace(/`(.*)`/, '<div class="code">$1</div>')
```

```css
.code {
  color: red;
}
```

`(.*)` means: any character one or more times.

`$1` means: the content of the first group (which inside `()`)

---

Or if you want to replace more than 1 time, you can try this.

```js
var str = 'This is some `code example 1` and very very fancy `code example 2` to try out yourself!';

document.body.innerHTML += str.replace(/`(.*?)`/g, '<div class="code">$1</div>')
```

```css
.code {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: You can reduce the star height by using ``/`(.*?)`/``

Answer (score 0):

You can use this invocation to replace `something` with `<div class="code">something</div>`:

```
someString.replace(/`([^`]*)`/, (match, p1) => `<div class="code">${p1}</div>`);
```